# Streamlining If statement c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, object, if-statement

I'm trying to use this statement

```
status_label.Text = err.Message + " || " + err.InnerException == null ? " " : err.InnerException.Message;
```

Basically if there is an InnerException because its not null, then show it, if it is null then don't output anything.

this is as streamlined as I think I can have it

```
 status_label.Text = err.Message;
 if (err.InnerException != null)
     status_label.Text += " || " + err.InnerException.Message;
```

Cheers.

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question.

Comment: I prefer your un-streamlined code. Much easier to read which will make it easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: I don't see a huge benefit in refactoring your code. Your concatenations should become string.Format()'s though, since strings are immutable in .Net.... (see J Torres' post).

Comment: sorry being at work, i have little time so on this particular occasion I hadn't read through the question properly, none the less it has still been answered really, and I have got the exact answer needed. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
status_label.Text =  err.InnerException == null 
    ? err.Message
    : err.Message + " || " + err.InnerException.Message;
```

Comment: This doesn't include the " || " when InnerException is not null.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest of the proposed solutions unless you're a "no concatenation" purist.

Comment: The thing is it, it doesn't need to be highly readable, a short comment will say exactly what it does so this is perfect solution! readabilty of code that outputs to label is not necessary but this still covers that aspect really well!

Comment: @No1_Melman Your logic is faulty—using comments as a substitute for readable code is a bad policy. However, this answer requires no additional commenting.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the brakets around the ternary operator

```
status_label.Text = err.Message + " || " + (err.InnerException == null ? " " : err.InnerException.Message);
```

or, if you don't want the || in case of null innerexception

```
status_label.Text = err.Message + (err.InnerException == null ? "" : " || " + err.InnerException.Message);
```

Comment: That will include the " || " even InnerException is null.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
status_label.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}", err.Message, err.InnerException != null ? string.Format(" || {0}", err.InnerException.Message) : string.Empty);
```

Comment: +1 : Ha. I was in the process of typing this -exact- answer.

Comment: I have to wonder why someone downvoted this...

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I find readability suffers here: string.Format nested in a ternary nested in another string.Format seems a bit much.

Comment: I agree it's not the most elegant code ever written, but the OP didn't ask for elegant... they asked for "how."  It's a bit rude for people to downvote when the solution provided is the most memory-efficient and correct solution provided.  It is what it is though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your if statement should be this

```
status_label.Text = err.Message;
 if (err.InnerException != null)
     status_label.Text += " || " + err.InnerException.Message;
```

As for making it more streamlined than this, you could make use of conditionals and / or null coalescing, but that is perfectly readable.

However, you could do this if you so preferred.

```
status_label.Text = string.Concat(err.Message, err.InnerException == null ? string.Empty : " || " + err.InnerException.Message);
```

Is that any more concise? Not really.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, if you don't mind the full Exception being printed you can do:

```
status_label.Text = err.ToString();
status_label.Text += err.InnerException;
```

(Bear in mind this will put a "System Exception:" or the like in front of each exception.)

Otherwise your code seems streamlined enough as is. (Readability is sometimes more desirable than compactness remember.)